# Error in Re-Installing MySQL Community Servers 8.0 on Windows 10

Tags: mysql

When I am trying to re-install MySQL Community Servers 8.0 on Windows 10, it is giving me the option just to update it and not to install it, although I have already deleted all the previous MySQL packages from my computer so that I can re-install it from scratch.

[image]

Comment: To remove MySQL: Control Panel > MySql...CE > change > remove

Comment: Also delete files from Regedit (window+R) type Regedit and check all files related to mysql